# How to compress video using LZ4 in android

Tags: android, compression, lz4

I want to compress video using `LZ4` library into my `android` application. I am using [this](https://github.com/lz4/lz4-java) library to compress my video file. Please help me to implement it correctly or suggest me any best alternative so that compression time should be fast. I have also tried with `ffmpeg` but it take too long time to compress video. Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you tried this https://github.com/yovenny/VideoCompress

Comment: @M.Yogeshwaran I have also tried with this library, everything works fine but take long time to compress video.

Comment: what is the size of your video